# Can IPFS app hide the CID when presenting content to requester?

Tags: ipfs, libp2p

Assume there is a IPFS app serving as a middleman to retrieve a content from IPFS network and present it to the requester. When the IPFS app receive an request (with no CID), then it finds the CID according to the request, retrieve with the CID and present to the requester. Is there a way the app can hide the CID when present the content to the requester? Similar to some online search, the resulting URL  is not human readable which effectively hides the real location of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hide CID from user interface by:

- using [DNSLink](http://dnslink.io), which hides CID and gives you DNS-based human-readable names
- putting go-ipfs behind a reverse proxy (such as Nginx) or adding some middleware app that takes care of mapping arbitrary paths to specific CIDs